# Prioritization of re-write rules in .htaccess and httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, httpd.conf

I'm confused on which file's rewriting rules gets hierarchy in an apache (xampp) server.

1. Do .htaccess rules get priority over httpd.conf rules?
2. If you can add the same rules to each, what is the difference between these two files?

What got me wondering about this stuff is because I'd like to update my favicon every second (for learning purposes) but the code below in my .htaccess file isn't working. My .htaccess file is in the server root folder along with my index.php file which is recognized when I go to `http://localhost`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 seconds"   
</IfModule>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: what does is the Content-Type http header say when you load the favicon. Favicons can have like 3 different MIME types, so image/x-icon might be the incorrect one.

Comment: hi Gerben, i don't know where to find content-Type http header in chrome developer tools or firebug, i've been told its in "resources" but can't find it there, can you suggest how i'd locate that? thanks

Comment: In firebug go to the net tab. Click the arrow next to the favicon request. Select the Headers tab, and under the Response Headers there should be a Content-Type with next to it its value.

Comment: I think the answers suggested here may help to shed some light on your question as well: http://serverfault.com/questions/258548/htaccess-vrs-httpd-conf#_=_

Comment: thanks Jeffrey, yes this link is helpful!

Comment: Er... `ExpiresActive` and `ExpiresByType` belong to `mod_expires`, not `mod_rewrite`.